# Unconvinced with the expectcation calculation on this one

Tags: probability, statistics, log-likelihood

I am frustrated with why this is happening.
The distribution is truncated Poisson with $\theta$ and $y_1,...,y_n$ observations.

If $l(\theta)$ denotes the log likelihood of the distribution, I need to find(skipped tedious calculations to get to this point but the $l''$ is correct)

> $$-\mathbb{E}[l''(\theta)]=-\mathbb{E}[\frac{-n\bar{y}}{\theta^2}+n\frac{e^{-\theta}}{(1-e^{-\theta})^2}]$$

Well, here are my steps

> $-\mathbb{E}[\frac{-n\bar{y}}{\theta^2}+n\frac{e^{-\theta}}{(1-e^{-\theta})^2}]=-\mathbb{E}[\frac{-n\bar{y}}{\theta^2}]-\mathbb{E}[n\frac{e^{-\theta}}{(1-e^{-\theta})^2}]=\frac{n}{\theta^2}\mathbb{E}[\bar{y}]-n\frac{e^{-\theta}}{(1-e^{-\theta})^2}$
>
> $\bar{y}=\frac{\Sigma y_i}{n}$ so therefore,
>
> $\frac{n}{\theta^2}\mathbb{E}[\bar{y}]-n\frac{e^{-\theta}}{(1-e^{-\theta})^2}=\frac{1}{\theta^2}\mathbb{E}[\Sigma y_i]-n\frac{e^{-\theta}}{(1-e^{-\theta})^2}=\frac{1}{\theta^2}n\theta-n\frac{e^{-\theta}}{(1-e^{-\theta})^2}$ since $y_i$ is distributed with truncated Poisson that has mean $\theta$.
>
> Thus $\frac{n}{\theta}-n\frac{e^{-\theta}}{(1-e^{-\theta})^2}$

However, the solution says the answer is

> $$n(\frac{1}{\theta(1-e^{-\theta})}-\frac{e^{-\theta}}{(1-e^{-\theta})^2})=\frac{n(1-e^{-\theta}-\theta e^{-\theta})}{\theta(1-e^{-\theta})^2}$$

Not convinced. Especially because it skips the calculation steps. I have been staring it for an hour, retried the calculation and no, I don't see a flaw in my steps. I need someone more experienced to point it out. I seriously cannot see why the answer got this form, in mine, I clearly cannot avoid having $(1-e^{-\theta})^2$ to calculate the fractions but the answer somehow manages to avoid that.

Comment: Could you write down the exact distribution you are using (there are different ways to 'truncate' a Poisson distribution....)....this way we could run a quick simulation and check numerically which result is correct.

Comment: If $X \sim \text{Poisson}(\theta)$, and $Y = X|X > 0$ is a truncated Poisson by removing the $0$, then $E[Y]$ no longer equals to $\theta$. Instead, it equals to $\displaystyle \frac {\theta} {1 - e^{-\theta}}$

Comment: oh alright, so it isn;'t $\theta$... thanks